# Long Crack in External Wall. What has caused this?

Tags: brick, crack, old-house, cracks

Viewed this victorian, end of terrace house- The only glaring problem is a lengthy crack running down the side. The estate agent has said that the owner had these addressed in a structural survey and it is just cosmetic. Would be great to get some more opinions.

[image]
[image]
[image]

There's also a smaller crack running through some old repair work (15 years+ ago)

[image]

Comment: Appear to be related to the new door and new window - or perhaps to the old door and old window that needed to be replaced.

Comment: Ask to see the survey, or have your own done. Never believe an estate agent. It depends whether it moved then stopped or is still moving. London houses do tend to shift over time, but you want to know before you buy it how bad it's likely to get. It could be ignorable or it could need under-pinning. You don't want to find that out after you buy it. I'm also intrigued by that …ermmm… interesting use of the 18mm copper span outside the building, going to what looks like a heater. If it's gas it should have been on 22mm. If it's water, then why the hell did they run it outside?

Comment: …That 45° pipe is also a prime candidate for pulling the trap dry. Those two fails would prompt me to also want to know how much more not to spec DIY has been done in the past. Survey needed. I also just noticed the cracks run through the new brickwork… which makes the movement either ongoing or recent.

Comment: …and what on earth is that - https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgZ7F.png - *is* it a drain, is it a supply??

Comment: @Tetsujin - condensate drain from the combi.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say but vertical cracks are never cosmetic. Any cracks which run though the bricks themselves are an issue because they can destabilise the wall.

The only cosmetic cracks are ones which follow the brickwork joints in a zig-zag fashion and even those can be caused by structural issues.

You need a structural engineer who will likely advise the fitting of tell-tales, special monitors which fit over the crack in several places. Measurements are then taken over a period to determine if the movement is still live and ongoing.

If the movement is still live, then you need to look at the ground. Leaking drains, recently removed trees, etc. etc. to find the cause of the moving ground. That needs to be addressed before any brickwork repairs.

Once it's all stable, all the cracked bricks need removing and replacing.